# wp_handle_upload returns empty error array

Tags: ajax, errors, uploads

I am trying to do an upload via ajax and really dont want to use the regular wordpress media uploader. It is too much stuff and all i want to do is upload single image.

I have everything working the ajax is sending the uploaded file via this Jquery plugin [LINK](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) I got it all set up and isn't the problem.

Here is my function that is being called to upload however i always am returned this error message.

```
    if ( !empty($_FILES['files']) ) {
        $daFile = $_FILES['files'];

        $upload = wp_handle_upload($daFile , array('test_form' => FALSE));
        var_dump($upload);

    }
```

and error message that is returned from $upload

```
   array(1) { ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) }}
```

Note I am using WPMU. I have checked online a ton about this but cant see why I am getting this blank error array...

This is for a front end uploader for users. Does wp_handle_upload care about user privileges ie if logged in or not admin? if so what should I do to just upload this damn thing to the server?  I just need the url link by the end of this function.

Thanks!

Comment: the plugin you linked to is set up to accept multiple images in a single field via the `multiple` attribute, are you sure `$_FILES['files']` isn't an array?

Comment: your right i left it as a multiple file upload so i can also pass additional formData to it for this to work. hmm i think files is an array... I thought that it needed to be... that's probably the problem what should I pass in to it instead?  here is the response of what var_dump returned from var_dump($daFile);  array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Koala.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/php4UnYgj" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(780831) }}

Comment: ahh i think i may need to pass $_FILES['files'][name] let me try that.. edit: no that isn't right either.

Comment: in your var dump, note how each of the array keys contain arrays- `name` is an array with length of 1, where that single array element contains the name in the form of a string. if it weren't a multiple file upload, `name` would just be a string. have a look in the [php docs at example #3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so Milo was on track to what the answer was. and I needed to brush up on muliple file uploads... anyway the solution for me to at least get it to upload... was this

```
    $daFile = $_FILES['files'];
    foreach ($_FILES['files'] as $key => $value) {

        $daFile[$key] = $value[0]; 

    }

    $upload = wp_handle_upload($daFile , array('test_form' => FALSE));
```

this worked for me and retuned the uploaded file.